# Parsing array in PHP from javascript JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

Im passing a json  object into php and when i try to parse the array im getting an error from php. I searched on how to parse an array but still having trouble figuring it out. Im getting the 500 response error in the console.

Here is the javascript:

```
var purchase = {
          items: [{ service: service }, { duration: duration }, { people: people }]
        };
        fetch("php/payment.php", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
        })
```

And here is the PHP

```
function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
    foreach ($items as $key => $value){
        $service = $value["service"];   /// If i remove this section it works
        $duration = $value["duration"]; /// If i remove this section it works
        $people = $value["people"];     /// If i remove this section it works
    }
  return 1111;
}
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    try {  
      // retrieve JSON from POST body
      $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
      $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
      $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
        'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($json_obj->items),
        'currency' => 'usd',
      ]);
      $output = [
        'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
      ];
      echo json_encode($output);
    } catch (Error $e) {
      http_response_code(500);
      echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop is incorrect:

```
foreach ($items as $key => $value){
    $service = $value["service"];   /// If i remove this section it works
    $duration = $value["duration"]; /// If i remove this section it works
    $people = $value["people"];     /// If i remove this section it works
}
```

With each iteration $key will hold one of "service", "duration" or "people", and the $value will be equal to the associations value, so also "service", "duration" or "people".

You can use either a switch statement:

```
foreach ($items as $key => $value){
    switch($key) {
        case "service": $service = $value; break;
        case "duration": $duration = $value; break;
        case "people" : $people = $value; break;
    }
}
```

Or if for some reason you wanted to create a temporary object, you could keep the loop as follows:

```
foreach ($items as $key => $value)
    $temp[$key] = $value;

$service = $temp["service"];
$duration = $temp["duration"];
$people = $temp["people"];
```